# !!! Tag ends here !!! while printing html in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, printing

I have simple HTML to print. When I try printing it from IE, I see text added there as "TAG ENDS HERE!!!".

The program basically pastes the inner html of the div i want to print in...

```
    var divElements = '<h3>Activity Report for divya12</h3>\n      <h4>Displaying Sales and Purchases, Issued Items</h4>\n      <h4>Period: 1/1/2015 to 9/7/2015</h4>';

    var tempBackUpPage = document.body.innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = divElements;  

    window.focus();

    window.print();
```

The text "TAG ENDS HERE" is not reproducible on other browsers, only on IE.
I tried to run the same in compatibility mode for IE, but still there was no change. 
I have also checked the HTML that was being generated but i failed to find any text stating "TAG ENDS HERE".
Printed content looks as follows:

.Activity Report for divya12

.

.Displaying Sales and Purchases, Issued Items

.Period: 1/1/2015 to 9/7/2015

.

.

.

!!!
TAG

ENDS

HERE !!!

Comment: Most likely `.l-report-header` contains the text you see. Have you checked `divElements` before replacing the content of the document.

Comment: @Teemu Yeah I copied the `divElement` in a separate html, but it does not have any text stating the above. and when we try printing in IE only then we see the text.

Comment: That looks like an incorrectly terminated comment, please check the source file. Or ... You're creating some content dynamically using `next/previousSibling` or other node listing method, which includes comments in the collection. Anyway, without the real code it's impossible to say, except: it is not IE printing method adding that text.